# Can I use an Apple remote to control a keynote presentation?

Tags: keynote, apple-remote-desktop

Is it possible to use the Apple remote to control Keynote presentations? How so? I have a mid-2010 white plastic unibody MacBook. (I've been told that this isn't supported, but perhaps there are third party solutions.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes - although most people are using the iOS based [Keynote Remote](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote-remote/id300719251?mt=8) these days, the old infrared (which is very thin / physically touchable and very reliable in dark rooms and easily hidden in a hand) works just fine.

The [Keynote '09 help](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Keynote/5.0/en/kyntc6c2e0c1.html) shows what functions the various buttons will perform when you are in the various modes: Keynote window itself, presentation mode and slide switcher mode.

[image: Apple Remote]

Comment: Would this work with my 2010 Unibody (white) MacBook?

Comment: If it has an IR receiver, yes.

Comment: Check your user manual (or system_profiler) to be sure, but my information shows unibody MacBooks do not have IR Receivers, so you would need an external one. http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/44372/5472

Comment: The white mid 2010 MacBook comes without an IR receiver.

Comment: @guwac These [mira receivers](http://twistedmelon.com/mira/hardware.html) work well in my experience if a specific Mac lacks infrared receivers as a built-in option.

Comment: I have my IR Apple Remote paired with an old 17" MacBookPro but Keynote 6.n
doesn't list the remote in the Application Preferences. Only wants iOS Remotes by the look of it. How can I get an older version of Keynote (without using a 3rd party DL site I've never heard of before)?

The IR remote is more discrete than an iPhone, and I paid a lot of money for it and barely used it yet. My older MBP has an IR reciever so why would they hobble it in Keynote 6. how many versions back in Keynote do I need to go to get IR remote working?