# What external IR receivers are there for Mac?

Tags: hardware, keynote, apple-remote-desktop

I have a 13" white unibody MacBook from 2010 which I'd like to use with the Apple remote, to control keynote presentations. According to [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44359/can-i-use-an-apple-remote-to-control-a-keynote-presentation), I need an external IR reciever for the remote to work with my MacBook. Would an IR receiver actually work, and if so, what are my options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking to control Keynote presentations and your Mac doesn't have a built-in IR port, you *could* buy an external receiver, but I suggest you use either:

- The [Keynote Remote app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/keynote-remote/id300719251?mt=8) for iPhone. This works over wi-fi and requires only a $0.99 purchase and no additional hardware to buy or set up.

  [image]

or

- A specialized slide advancer, like this [Logitech](http://www.logitech.com/en-ca/mice-pointers/presentation-remote/devices/5873) one. This is designed to be comfortable to hold (the Apple Remote wasn't) and doesn't require line-of-sight to the receiver (which is a small USB dongle) to work. Some of the better ones have a slide counter and laser pointers built in.

  [image]

Comment: I love the Apple remote but I have no excuse to buy one now. I have the Keynote remote app and I happen to not like it very much.

Comment: @Moshe Then I recommend the slide advancer. Some of the better ones even have built-in slide counters and laser pointers.